# Line type data plot doesn't appear

Tags: python, dataframe, dataset

There is this dataset that I'm going to plot (it can be obtained here https://www.kaggle.com/russellyates88/suicide-rates-overview-1985-to-2016). I wanted to plot the suicides_no for male and female, 25-34 years old in Russian Federation, from 2000 to 2015. So I create a new data frame for that.

Here's the main data frame.

```
DF = pd.read_csv("D:/who_suicide_statistics.csv")
```

Here's my code for creating the new data frame.

```
DF1 = (DF.loc[(DF["country"] == "Russian Federation") & (DF["age"] == "25-34 years") 
        & (DF["sex"] == "male") & (DF["year"] >= 2000)])
DF2 = (DF.loc[(DF["country"] == "Russian Federation") & (DF["age"] == "25-34 years") 
        & (DF["sex"] == "female") & (DF["year"] >= 2000)])

year_sex_suicides = {}
year_sex_suicides["year"] = DF1["year"]
year_sex_suicides["male_suicides"] = DF1["suicides_no"]
year_sex_suicides["female_suicides"] = DF2["suicides_no"]
DF333 = pd.DataFrame(data=year_sex_suicides)
```

And here is the code for the plot that I wanted.

```
DF333.plot(kind="line", x="year", y=["male suicides", "female_suicides"])
```

The graph I came up with is this

[image: plot]

There's something wrong but I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

You likely have quite some `NaN`s in the dataset you're trying to plot (look at your DataFrame by evaluating `print(DF333)` for example).

You could either fill them up using something like (which is not a good way though!):

```
DF333.fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)
```

Or reset the index when building your dataframe:

```
DF1 = (DF.loc[(DF["country"] == "Russian Federation") & (DF["age"] == "25-34 years") 
        & (DF["sex"] == "male") & (DF["year"] >= 2000)])
DF1 = DF1.set_index('year')
DF2 = (DF.loc[(DF["country"] == "Russian Federation") & (DF["age"] == "25-34 years") 
        & (DF["sex"] == "female") & (DF["year"] >= 2000)])
DF2 = DF2.set_index('year')

year_sex_suicides = {}
year_sex_suicides["male_suicides"] = DF1["suicides_no"]
year_sex_suicides["female_suicides"] = DF2["suicides_no"]
DF333 = pd.DataFrame(data=year_sex_suicides)

DF333.plot(kind="line", y=["male_suicides", "female_suicides"])
```

That way, you ensure that everything is put in the row that matches the year, and not the row index from the original CSV file. Of course, you could also use something like Panda's [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), which will reduce the number of lines of code as well (but maybe you need `DF1` etc. later on for other purposes too):

```
DF1 = DF.loc[(DF["country"] == "Russian Federation") & (DF["age"] == "25-34 years")  
       & (DF["year"] >= 2000)]
DF1.groupby(['year', 'sex']).sum()['suicides_no'].groupby('sex').plot()
```